# How to create a new apple distribution certificate when maximum limit of creating certificates has been reached

Tags: ios, iphone

I am facing problem with the apple distribution certificate. I have to create a new certificate, but I have already reached the maximum limits. I am unable to use old distribution certificates also, as the certificates do not have their matching private keys. I have done a lot of R&D on it, but still I have not got the solution to my problem.
I don't want to revoke the older certificates.

Comment: Do you have a paid developer membership?

Comment: yes, i do have a paid developer membership.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is instead of creating new certificates, revoke the older certificate and then create a new one. as after the creation of maximum number of certificates new certificates cannot be created until you revoke the older ones.